# Share mouse and keyboard between PC and Mac

Tags: mac, usb, keyboard, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a better solution to share keyboard, mouse and monitor between mac and PC](https://superuser.com/questions/250868/what-is-a-better-solution-to-share-keyboard-mouse-and-monitor-between-mac-and-pc)

I'm looking for a way to share a keyboard/mouse between my PC and Mac.

I looked at Synergy, but this appears to require the server to be always running. This is not an option for me (do not want to waste energy). I'm looking for something like a USB hub but with a hardware switch that allows me to toggle between PC and Mac. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [KVM Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).